# Sharing on instagram + localhost sharing

Tags: wordpress, share, social-networking, yoast

I'm workng on a **wordpress** website in my computer (so **localy**).

When I share a link (on **twitter** and **FB**), my **meta data** for social media (**open graph** and the one for Twitter) are not considered. Is that because I'm on localhost ? I'm using **Yoast**.

And another question about **Instagram** : I can find anything like the *sharer* of FB. Instagram doesn't give the possibility to share article from a blog to Instagram ?

Comment: Facebook probably can't read your local servers data.

Comment: That's what I've thought. And what about instragram ?

Comment: @ProjetSin Yes, you cannot share blogs directly on Instagram, especially if you are trying to do so using the Instagram.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Weird, knowing that Instagram belong to facebook

Answer (score 0):

Inside your configuration file, you should set false  facabook/instagram ssl verification as false.